# Сохранить все картинки png со страницы

Tags: python, requests, beautiful-soup

Как сохранить все картинки, а именно `.png`, которые находятся на странице? Мой код не работает:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get("https://www.soccerstand.com/ru/match/4haX78Hq/#/match-summary")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

images = [img for img in soup.find_all("img") if ".png" in img.get("src")]

for i, image in enumerate(images):
    img_data = requests.get(image["src"]).content
    with open(f"image_{i}.png", "wb") as f:
        f.write(img_data)
```

Comment: soup.find_all("img") не находить тег "img". Уж постарайтесь сделать соответствующие выводы. Проанализируйте response.text на наличия нужных вам данных.

Answer (score 0):

попробуй так

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get("https://www.soccerstand.com/ru/match/4haX78Hq/#/match-summary")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

images = [img for img in soup.find_all("img") if ".png" in img.get("src")]

for i, image in enumerate(images):
    img_url = image["src"]
    if not img_url.startswith("http"):
        # Если указано относительное URL, необходимо дополнить его до абсолютного
        img_url = "https://www.soccerstand.com" + img_url
    img_data = requests.get(img_url).content
    with open(f"image_{i}.png", "wb") as f:
        f.write(img_data)
```

(должно сработать)

Comment: а проверить забыли))